# Read Apple nvram

Tags: linux, macintosh, uefi

On Mac OS X there is a tool called *nvram* to get and set EFI properties. As I am now deploying GNU/Linux on Apple hardware, I'd like to have a similar tool that is able to talk to Apple's EFI implementation.

Are there tools to achieve this?

Comment: you should just be able to read them with the `efivars` program available via package manager. However, if you took the *(horrible!)* advice offered by many - such as at this [Ubuntu/Mac how-to](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MactelSupportTeam/AppleIntelInstallation) - and converted your disk to a Hybrid MBR so you might boot Linux in legacy *(read - BIOS)* mode, then those variables are not available to you and will not be until you boot the Linux kernel in EFI-mode. [Here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/ubuntu-efi/) is a far better tutorial on the subject.

Comment: There's /sys/firmware/efi/vars/ holding those on my UEFI compatible systems upon efivars.ko module load but it was known a year or two ago that loading it might corrupt Apple's firmware, it was advised that one backs it up and has the backout plan/tools handy (see also http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/installation.html).

Comment: @mikeserv `efivars` works, at least for reading. About all those Apple-Firmwares-Will-Be-Destroyed-Warnings... I never got authoritative information about that.

Comment: @mikeserv Would you write an answer about `efivars`?

Comment: I dont have any Apples and so i dont know the ins and outs well enough to make any *authoritative* calls in that respect. Youre far better off cruising rodsbooks as Michael has suggested - Rod Smith is about as authoritative as it gets in my opinion on this subject. I do know that theres little mystery there - i can read those with `printf` and `od` in a pinch. You might also look into the `clover` bootloader forums - which is the other active refit fork and is what all of the hackintosh guys use. I am curious though and i may dig into it. Can i ask - what do you wanna do with them?

Comment: OS X stores several interesting settings there, like information about Bluetooth pairings, Wifi associations, current keyboard layout and more.

Comment: @MaxRied - but you can *read* those, yes? I can't imagine there can be any danger in *reading* the variables, and I am a little dubious about any danger in writing to them as well - though, as I've just learned, apparently Apple's bootmanager hijacks the normal EFI boot process depending on the value set in some of their own NVRAM vars and skips the FAT formatted ESP by default. I can imagine that if one of these values were to change the boot process might go pretty wonky. In any case, the only problem I've ever known of was a kernel bug that wrote too much to NVRAM effectively wiping it.

Answer (score 1):

The tools available are going to vary between Linux distributions, but with a Ubuntu 16.04 LTS live ISO booted from a USB stick on a 2011 MacBook Pro, nvram variables are readable in the filesystem:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ cd /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/
ubuntu@ubuntu:/sys/firmware/efi/efivars$ ls
AAPL,PathProperties0000-4d1ede05-38c7-4a6a-9cc6-4bcca8b38c14
AcpiGlobalVariable-af9ffd67-ec10-488a-9dfc-6cbf5ee22c2e
[...]
ThorUpdateResult-7c436110-ab2a-4bbb-a880-fe41995c9f82
Timeout-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
ubuntu@ubuntu:/sys/firmware/efi/efivars$ hexdump -C Lang-*
00000000  07 00 00 00 65 6e 67                              |....eng|
00000007
```

To modify variables, install the `efivar` tool with `apt`.